# Go []byte to Little/Big-Endian Signed Integer or Float?

Tags: go, types, slice

I am able to convert `[]byte` into unsigned integers:

```
a := binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(sampleA)
b := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(sampleB)
```

This leverages the BigEndian and LittleEndian types within the Go package  https://golang.org/src/encoding/binary/binary.go.

This provides `Uint16()` however there are no equivalent `Int16()` or `Float32()`.

Any thoughts on why not? Also, how ought this be done?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Converting numeric types into a series of bytes (`[]byte`) and vice versa is about the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). How you interpret the result is entirely up to you.

All you need is to assemble a 16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit value, once it's done, you can interpret the result as you want.

For example if you already have a `uint16` value, to use it as a signed value, all you need is a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) because the memory layout of an `uint16` and `int16` is the same (converting from `uint16` to `int16` doesn't change the memory representation just the type):

```
a := binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(sampleA)
// If you need int16:
a2 := int16(a)
```

Similarly:

```
a := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(sampleA)
// If you need int64:
a2 := int64(a)
```

The situation is a little more complicated with uint -> float conversion as using a simple type conversion would try to convert the numeric value and not just change the type (and thus would change the memory representation).

For converting unsigned integers to float types, you can use functions of the [`math`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/) package, namely [`math.Float32frombits()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float32frombits) and [`math.Float64frombits()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float64frombits), and for the reverse direction (converting a float value to an unsigned integer) having the same memory layout: [`math.Float32bits()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float32bits) and [`math.Float64bits()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float64bits).

For example:

```
a := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(sampleA)
// If you need a float64:
a2 := math.Float64frombits(a)
```

If you would look into the implementation of these functions from the `math` package, you can see that the memory value/layout is not manipulated, it is just "viewed" as a different type, by using the [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) package. For example:

```
func Float32frombits(b uint32) float32 { return *(*float32)(unsafe.Pointer(&b)) }
```

As mentioned by Paul, the `binary` package provides [`Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) and [`Write()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write) functions to do these conversions under the hood so you don't need to.

Showcasing using the same "pi" example (from the doc of `binary.Read()`):

```
b := []byte{0x18, 0x2d, 0x44, 0x54, 0xfb, 0x21, 0x09, 0x40}

// USING binary.Read()
var pi float64
buf := bytes.NewReader(b)
err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &pi)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("binary.Read failed:", err)
}
fmt.Println(pi)

// Using LittleEndian.Uint64() and math.Float64frombits()
a := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(b)
a2 := math.Float64frombits(a)
fmt.Println(a2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/IoWaE2tlZ6)):

```
3.141592653589793
3.141592653589793
```

Answer (score 5):

The `ByteOrder` type provides a low-level API for decoding binary values. To read float64 or other types, you can use `binary.Read`. There's an [example](http://play.golang.org/p/lJ_NTZC4h2) on the [godoc page for the binary package](https://godoc.org/encoding/binary#Read), which I've copied here:

```
var pi float64
b := []byte{0x18, 0x2d, 0x44, 0x54, 0xfb, 0x21, 0x09, 0x40}
buf := bytes.NewReader(b)
err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &pi)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("binary.Read failed:", err)
}
fmt.Print(pi)
```

There's no functions for decoding float16, because that's not a type in Go.