# Convert one pointer to another type in golang

Tags: pointers, go

I want to convert a float64 number into int64 number. That is, I want to read the binary contents of the float64 register as if it is a int64 value. I mean, I want the go equivalent of the following C code

```
long y;
float x = 1.2;
y  = * ( long * ) &x;
```

How do I do that?

Here is my try which is not working.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    x := float64(1.2)
    y := *((*int64)(&x))

    fmt.Println("Ans:  ", y)

}
```

Comment: To convert it directly to int64 is not enough? `y := int64(x)`

Comment: Related, answers your question as well: [Go byte slice to Little/Big-Endian Signed Integer or Float?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701187/go-byte-to-little-big-endian-signed-integer-or-float)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> That is, I want to read the binary contents of the float64 register as
>   if it is a int64 value.

Try `math.Float64bits`:

```
x := float64(1.2)
fmt.Printf("Ans:  %x", math.Float64bits(x))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/QB4jqwJD0f

Prints `Ans: 3ff3333333333333`.

Answer (score 2):

Go doesn't allow conversions between different types of pointers as it is inherently unsafe. But, if you still want to do it there is a `Pointer` type in `unsafe` package, which represents a pointer to an arbitrary type.

Any type of pointer can be converted to `unsafe.Pointer` and `unsafe.Pointer` can be converted to any type of pointer as long as they have the same memory structure. This allows you to ignore the type system and interpret any type of data as data of any other type.

The exact equivalent of the C code in your example in Go would be:

```
var y int64
var x float64 = 1.2
y = *(*int64)(unsafe.Pointer(&x))
```

So first we convert `&x` to `unsafe.Pointer`, then convert that to `*int64` and finally dereference that to get an `int64` with the same bit structure as `x`.

Remember that there is a reason this is in `unsafe` package. If you just want to know what the bits are, it's better to use `math.Float64bits()`. But if for example you must use bitwise operators on `float` then of course you have to convert it to `int` (and back).