# Converting between a 3-byte slice and signed integer type

Tags: go, integer, deserialization, byte, twos-complement

I have a slice consisting of 3 bytes (ordered in LE) that is representing a signed integer, and I want to convert it to any of the integer types, preferably `int32`, and then back to itself.

```golang
b := []byte{0x01, 0x00, 0x80}
```

I tried to do that using `big.Int`, but it seemed like its `SetBytes()` and `Bytes()` methods only work for unsigned integer types, regardless of that a `big.Int` instance can also store signed integer types.

Here is a Python equivalent of what I’m trying to do:

```py
b = b"\x01\x00\x80"
i = int.from_bytes(b, "little", signed=True)
b_again = int.to_bytes("little", signed=True)
```

Edit: This question is not a duplicate of [Go []byte to Little/Big-Endian Signed Integer or Float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701187/go-byte-to-little-big-endian-signed-integer-or-float). I have tried applying the answers there, but their results weren’t expected. See my first comment.

Comment: No, I also tried adding an empty byte to the slice and use `encoding/binary` to initialize it to an `int32`, but its results were incorrect.

Comment: Note that in addition to the answer which addresses your problem you will likely need to have a slice with the number of bytes equal to that of your target type. How exactly to do that, is an open question. I would be sure to read the data into a large enough slice (with enough capacity) and then reslice it to the target length.

Comment: @kostix As I said, I made the number of bytes equal to an `int32` by adding an empty byte to the slice.

Comment: I have reopened the question as Python's `int.from_bytes(..., signed=True)` appears to implicitly assume the missing byte is `0xFF`, not `0x00`. Looks like `signed` should have been named `negative`, but that's just my first impression. [Here](https://go.dev/play/p/EluaD493BkS) is the explanation.

Comment: IOW, you cannot parse an LE `int32` composed of `0x01, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00` with that 0x00 being an MSB and expect it to be negative.

Comment: My take is that Python's `int.from_bytes(..., signed=True)` sign-extends the most significant _bit_ of the last byte (0x80) producing 0xFF. And it looks like it's sort of "non-greedy" in the sense it "pads in" just as many bytes to get an integer of the nearest (smallest) possible size–4 bytes in this case. So, to replicate this behavior in Go, you'd need to basically implement the same logic.

Comment: [One possible solution](https://go.dev/play/p/56t7hSIJnlK) is as follows: 1) pad by 0x00 "on the left", not "on the right"–that is, add a byte which will become the MSB; 2) after type-converting the result to the target _signed_ type shift right by 8×number of missing bytes bits–8 in your particular case. This will do an arithmetic shift, extensing the sign bit.

Comment: «add a byte which will become the MSB»–sorry, this should have been «will become the LSB», of course: the byte which will be shifted out from the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a slice consisting of 3 bytes (ordered in LE) that is representing a signed integer, and I want to convert it to any of the integer types, preferably int32, and then back to itself.

---

```
package main

import "fmt"

func ByteLE3ToInt24(b []byte) int32 {
    i := uint32(b[0])<<8 | uint32(b[1])<<16 | uint32(b[2])<<24
    return int32(i) >> 8
}

func Int24ToByteLE3(i int32) []byte {
    return []byte{byte(i), byte(i >> 8), byte(i >> 16)}
}

func main() {
    b := []byte{0x01, 0x00, 0x80} // Negative
    fmt.Println(b)
    fmt.Println(ByteLE3ToInt24(b))
    fmt.Println(Int24ToByteLE3(ByteLE3ToInt24(b)))
    fmt.Println()
    b = []byte{0x01, 0x00, 0x00} // Positive
    fmt.Println(b)
    fmt.Println(ByteLE3ToInt24(b))
    fmt.Println(Int24ToByteLE3(ByteLE3ToInt24(b)))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/tI8E2kSXopZ

```
[1 0 128]
-8388607
[1 0 128]

[1 0 0]
1
[1 0 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Little-Endian means that the number `0x01020304` is encoded as the byte squence `[]byte{4, 3, 2, 1}`.

Your example number has three bytes, so I assume that you mean `0x00010080` (left-filled with a zero-byte).

There is a type `encoding/binary.ByteOrder` with the two instances `LittleEndian` and `BigEndian` which provide functions to convert to and from bytes:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var b [4]byte
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(b[:], 0x00010080)
    i32 := int32(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(b[:]))
    fmt.Println(b)   // Prints [128 0 1 0].
    fmt.Println(i32) // Prints 65664 (which is 0x00010080).
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, a solution like this was previously tried and produces incorrect results. For 0x010080, the result must be -8388607, but your example produces 65664.